# Declare scalar variable exception while populating DataGridview with data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to put data from a SQL query into a DataGridview, but when I try to run the program I am getting the exception

> must declare scalar variable @cathedra

Here is the code:

```
string connectionString = "user id=bogdan_db; password=1234;server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=cafedrascience; connection timeout=30";
string sql = @"select *
               from researc r inner join research_cafadra rc on r.id = rc.researc_id
                    inner join cathedra c on c.id = rc.cafadre_id
               where c.name like @Cathedra;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Cathedra", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString); //c.con is the connection string
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Where I am mistaking?

Comment: Please put the query inside your `using` scope.

Comment: The [tag:microsoft] tag should not be used, as stated in the tag wiki (though its continued existence is problematic in itself); this is further to the Meta question asked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293754/82548.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're executing the query twice (and also connecting to the database twice). Please delete `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and change

`SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);`

to

`SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);`

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the parameter to `command`, which would be correct if you were actually using `command`. You're not... you call `ExecuteNonQuery()` and do nothing else with it.

You can remove these lines:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Cathedra", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And add this one after creating `dataAdapter`:

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cathedra", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Half-way fixes it.  He's still creating two database connections with this solution.